# Codeigniter search term with pagination

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller, pagination, search-form

Still getting to grips with PHP and Codeigniter and I'm having an issue with passing a search term parameter from my Controller to my Model, with pagination.

I have a fully functioning script (with pagination) working already... However, trying to include the input post search term to the model is messing it all up (or I'm messing it all up).

Working script - Controller:

```
    public function search()
    {
$this->load->model('Products_model');
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/products/search/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('affiliate_window');
$config['per_page'] = 25;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['offset_no'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['items'] = $this->Products_model->get_search($config['per_page'], $data['offset_no']);
$this->load->view('header_view');
$this->load->view('products_view', $data);
$this->load->view('footer_view');
    }
```

Working script - Model:

```
                function get_search($limit, $offset)
                {
$query = $this->db->get('mydb', $limit, $offset);
return $query->result();
                }
```

So, any advice on how do I now go about passing $this->input->post('search_term'); from Controller to my model to use like this:

```
                function get_search($limit, $offset)
                {
$this->db->like('name', '$SEARCHTERM');
$query = $this->db->get('mydb', $limit, $offset);
return $query->result();
                }
```

Furthermore, I believe I'm next going to run into an issue with keeping the search term variable throughout each page.

Any advice very welcome - I've been working on this for hours with no results! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, understand that your pagination code & all the other code are "unrelated" - meaning, they don't require the other one to function.

You will pass your search term in to your model function like any other parameter & search on it in the query; limit & offset are simply tagged to the end of your query as you are doing now.

So if searching for "myterm", you'll just build a query with:

```
WHERE term = "myterm" LIMIT offset, limit
```

It's really quite simple once you get your head around what you are actually doing